# Does begin . . . end while denote a 'block'?

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
temp = 98.3
begin
  print "Your temperature is " + temp.to_s + " Fahrenheit. "
  puts "I think you're okay."
  temp += 0.1
end while temp < 98.6
```

In the above example, is everything between begin and end a block?

I'm still confused what a block is.

If you can't call it a block, what would you call that chunk of code between begin and end? Is it ok to call it a chunk?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Block has a special meaning in Ruby.  [According to Matz](http://www.artima.com/intv/closures.html), Ruby's creator, you can look at a block as a nameless function - typically something that can be [`yield`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm)ed into, and which may also take parameters.

You may see the following kind of disamiguation when describing Ruby syntax:

- `begin`...`end` (what is called block in *other* languages) may sometimes be referred to simply as what it is, i.e. an [*expression*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_expressions.html) (which may in turn contain other expressions - an expression is simply something that has a return value) in Ruby.  Some references will still call it a `begin/end block`, or a `code block`, adding somewhat to the confusion
- `do`...`end` or `{...}` will always be referred to as a [*block*](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_containers.html) in Ruby

For examples, peruse the [the Ruby syntax man page](http://docs.huihoo.com/ruby/ruby-man-1.4/syntax.html), e.g.

> `begin` *`expression`* `end`
>   *`expression`* `while` *`expression`*
>   `loop` *`block`*

For further reading, see:

- [Programming Ruby](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/)
- [Ruby (from other languages)](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/ruby-from-other-languages/)
- [Much, much more](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/) documentation

Answer (score 9):

`begin/end` are strictly control flow, not blocks.

```
begin
  puts "hi"
end
# => "hi"
```

The code runs immediately. If it was a block, it would have to been called somehow in order for the code in it to run, as in this example:

```
def a_method; end
a_method { puts "hi" }
# nothing..

def a_method
  yield
end

a_method { puts "Hi!" }
# => "Hi!"
```