# What does Ruby's BEGIN do?

Tags: ruby

What does `BEGIN` mean in Ruby, and how is it called? For example, given this code:

```
puts "This is sentence 1."

BEGIN {
  puts "This is sentence 2."
}
```

why is `puts "This is sentence 2."` executed first?

Comment: _"and why is `This is sentence 2` executed first?"_ you sure about that?

Comment: wierd. I've never seen this keyword before.

Comment: @Alex: BEGIN is a carryover from Perl: http://docs.ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UA

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`BEGIN` and `END` set up blocks that are called before anything else gets executed, or after everything else, just before the interpreter quits.

For instance, running this:

```
END { puts 'END block' }

puts 'foobar'

BEGIN { puts 'BEGIN block' }
```

Outputs:

```
BEGIN block
foobar
END block
```

Normally we'd use a bit more logical order for the `BEGIN` and `END` blocks, but that demonstrates what they do.

Comment: Personally I think the formatting on the output is really confusing… I keep thinking it’s code—which it’s not. But to each his own.

Comment: In HTML we are supposed to use `<samp>` for code output but [Markdown doesn't support it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/135909/153968). `<samp>` is a fixed-width output, similar to what `<code>` or the backticks do. Color output occurs because there isn't a meta tag to turn off coloring. Using a `>` block uses a variable-width font and enables wrapping, neither of which are correct for code output.

Comment: Actually, you can turn off highlighting with `<!-- language: lang-none -->`. See [this meta answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81971/158402) for more.

Comment: Ah nice, didn't know that.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Ruby docs for the `BEGIN` keyword](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-BEGIN):

> `BEGIN`: Designates, via code block, code to be executed unconditionally before sequential execution of the program begins. Sometimes used to simulate forward references to methods.

Answer (score 4):

`BEGIN` and `END` Blocks

Every Ruby source file can declare blocks of code to be run as the file is being loaded (the `BEGIN` blocks) and after the program has finished executing (the `END` blocks).

```
BEGIN { 
   begin block code 
} 

END { 
   end block code 
}
```

A program may include multiple `BEGIN` and `END` blocks. `BEGIN` blocks are executed in the order they are encountered. `END` blocks are executed in reverse order.

You can find almost the same post in "[Does begin . . . end while denote a 'block'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/641743/does-begin-end-while-denote-a-block)".

Read more about blocks on [tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_blocks.htm)