# Why do while modifiers behave differently with blocks?

Tags: ruby

```
irb(main):186:0* begin puts "abc" end while false
abc
=> nil
irb(main):187:0> puts "abc" while false
=> nil
```

So when you use a block with the while modifier, the block is executed once (which seems like a do-while loop in many other languages). But if you use a single statement with the while modifier then it becomes more like just a while loop, where the condition is checked first. This seeks kind of surprising so why does the behavior exist?

Comment: In the latter the condition is executed first-consider if it wasn't, and what would happen to statements like `puts foo unless true`. The single-line syntax simply wouldn't work if the condition wasn't evaluated before the statement it suffixes.

Comment: I found this: https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/11/13/weird-ruby-begin-end/ which led to http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/6745 where Matz himself says “I'm regretting this feature, and I'd like to remove it in the future if it's possible.”

Comment: @matt so basically "it was a bad idea". maybe you should post as answer as it more or less answers the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be just a quirk of the language. `... while condition` acts a a statement modifier *except* when it is after a `begin ... end`, where it behaves like a `do ... while` loop from other languages.

Yukihiro Matsumoto (Matz, the creator of Ruby) has [said he regrets this, and would like to remove this behaviour in the future if possible](http://blade.nagaokaut.ac.jp/cgi-bin/scat.rb/ruby/ruby-core/6745).

There’s a bit more info in this blog post from New Relic, where I found the link to the mail list post: https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/11/13/weird-ruby-begin-end/

Answer (score 1):

I think your confusion lies in the fact that `begin/end` [is not considered a block](https://stackoverflow.com/a/641759/3109182).  To showcase your example with a block take a look at this:

```
[3] pry(main)> loop { puts "hi" } while false
=> nil
```

Comment: Regardless of implementation, it seems like the two should behave the same way as they look almost the same.

Comment: You're questioning the implementation of two different objects, hard to not call attention to that detail.

Answer (score 1):

Do while ensures at least one execution, but the second one is not a do while, is one of many sintax sugar of ruby.  Its equivalent to

```
while false
  puts 'abc'
end
```

Just remember the

```
puts 'abc' if false
```

Both are behaviouring correctly.

Comment: This doesn't explain why such similar constructs behave differently though

Comment: They look similar, but they aren't the same.  The first is a do while, the second is a while declared in just one line just for convenience.